# EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1) Error in Master-Detail App

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

My iPad app is crashing when I change the detail view.  I set an exception breakpoint to pinpoint the line(s) of code causing the issue.  It seems to happen rather sporadically so I'm not really sure what's going on. Any suggestions?

For example, it crashed on this line:

```
self.splitViewController.viewControllers = details;
```

in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method in my master view controller

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        KFBDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[KFBDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"KFBDetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

        NSMutableArray *details = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

        [details replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:detailNavigationController];

        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = details;

        KFBAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KFBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    }
```

It also did it here in another view:

```
appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers = details;
```

Here is the didSelectRowAtIndexPath for that one:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *details = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

    UINavigationController *detailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:webViewController];

    [details replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:detailNav];

    KFBAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KFBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers = details;
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = webViewController;

    [appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillAppear:YES];

    // Grab the selected item
    RSSItem *entry = [[channel items]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSLog(@"Channel Items: %@", [[channel items]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);

    // Construct a URL with the link string of the item
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[entry link]];

    NSLog(@"Link: %@", [entry link]);

    // Construct a request object with that URL
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);

    // Load the request into the web view
    [[webViewController webView]loadRequest:req];
    webViewController.hackyURL = url;
    NSLog(@"Request: %@", req);

    // Set the title of the web view controller's navigation item
    [[webViewController navigationItem]setTitle:[entry title]];

    NSLog(@"Title: %@", [entry title]);
}
```

**EDIT: The app seems to crash when I select the first row in the master view controller table view to show the initial detail view then select another row to show different content.  Everything works fine if I don't select the first row at any point.**

Comment: Why are you setting the window's root view controller to the split view controller? Isn't it already the root view controller?

Comment: You might find this helpful when debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors as I have sometimes. The gist of it is use 'register read' command in the debugger and look at the registers to determine the last function called before it crashes. From that you can determine the object you're trying to use that function on. And once you know which dealloced object is being accessed you can figure out how to safely call for it or retain it somehow. http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html

Comment: You may also need this http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html for the link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem by adjusting how I show the initial detail view when tapping the first row in master view.

You can see the original implementation in my original post.  Here is how I changed it.

```
if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        KFBDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[KFBDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"KFBDetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

        NSMutableArray *details = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

        UINavigationController *detailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

        [details replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:detailNav];

        KFBAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KFBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers = details;
        appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
        appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
        [appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
    }
```